# Getting Memory leak on android fragment

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-arrayadapter

I've been searching for a solution of the "memory leaks" problem on my android app, but, here is the thing:
 
I'm loading a fragment inside a viewpager, this fragment have a Gridview and an Adapter (ArrayAdapter) which creates each item of the gridview, these items have an image and some text (i'm using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), to load images.)
I'm getting a lot of memory leaks when i change the device orientation.

- I've changed all adapters context to an ApplicationContext.
- I've changed the image loader plugin (Universal Image Loader) to
  [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).
- I've changed the ArrayAdapter to a BaseAdapter.
- I've changed the Gridview to a FlowLayoutView and added all items as a View to this new ViewGroup.
- Also tested without "debugging" with android.

Not one of these changes worked, I'm still getting the memory leak, so, any help is welcome!

Edited:

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {

public MoviesFragment() {
}

final String TAG = MoviesFragment.class.toString();
ExpandableHeightGridView movieGridView;
MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;
ArrayList<Movie> movies;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    movies = args.getParcelableArrayList("movies");
    mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), movies);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
    movieGridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_movies);

    if (movies != null) {

        movieGridView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
        movieGridView.setExpanded(true);
        movieGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(
                        new EventSelectedEvent((Movie) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
            }
        });
    } else {
        movieGridView.setExpanded(false);
    }
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
```

}

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

Context context;

public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movies) {
    super(context, 0, movies);
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Movie movie = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext().getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_card_movies, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView movieName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_movie_text);

    //Load square image
    Image squareImg = movie.getSquareImage();
    if (null != squareImg) {
        ImageLoader iLoader = ImageLoaderHandler.getImageLoader(TandasApplication.getInstance());
        iLoader.displayImage(squareImg.getLink(),
                (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_movie_image));
    }

    //Title
    movieName.setText(movie.getTitle());

    //Rating
    LinearLayout ratingContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingMovieMainView);
    double rating = movie.getRating();
    UIUtils.buildRatingStars(rating, ratingContainer, context);

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without much information to go on, I think you are holding on to your fragment references.

Test this by using the adb shell command dumpsys

```
adb shell dumpsys activity <package_name>
adb shell dumpsys meminfo <package_name>
```

Navigate various fragments and run this after each time you navigate one of them. Meminfo will tell you how many activities are being held by the app. Activity break everything down for you.

If you post some logs or code, I can help you better.

Comment: Hi, i posted some code, when i change the device orientation, the MoviesFragment onCreateView is setting a new adapter.

Comment: This: this.context = context.getApplicationContext(); can create leaks. You don't want your adapters to use an application context, instead use the activity context.

Comment: Best not to keep a reference to the context at all - you can use convertView.getContext() instead where you were using it.

Comment: You are right that it is best not to keep a reference to context at all, however you do not want to use convertView.getcontext() because it can be null. Instead you want to use parent.getContext() since parent will never be null.